# Wifi 6 network not showing in available networks

Tags: wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Extreme X1 Gen 2 (win 11) with an intel WIFI 6 ax200 wireless adapter.  The wifi at home is ZenWwifiifi ET12.  (family xmas present this year)  Phones will connect fine to the wifi 6 network, and so will one of my pc's with a wifi 6 adapter.  My lenovo laptop with the above adapter won't see the wifi 6 network at all.  Things I've tried.

1. remove adapter (in computer management)
2. update driver to latest.  Currently 22.190.0.4
3. remove driver and rollback to 22.18xx
4. mess with the 802.11n/ac/ax mode.  Set to individual modes etc.

As an aside, it connects just fine to the 2.4/5 networks.

Any help and/or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `ZenWwifiifi` bit of a stutter :p - Wifi 6 is only 2.4Ghz/5GHz - so a Wifi 6 adapter won't use Wifi 6E's 6GHz band - you'd need an Intel AX210 for 6E

Comment: @JaromandaX, make that an answer and I'll mark it correct.  I bought a new AX210 wifi card for $25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ET12 router wifi 6E 6 ghz network need support apapter like [AX210 or above](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/details/wireless/wi-fi-6e-series/products.html) to use.

AX200 adapter only support 2.4/5 ghz band.